# Bad email format with django

Tags: python, django

I am new in web development with django. And am testing a website for deployment but when I receive email from my contact page to my gmail account, I will see 'From me to me' instead of 'from sender to me'. Please see screenshot below:  [From me to me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SNdK.png) and when I open the email it looks like this [when I open the email](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQsJr.png). Please someone should help me to fix this.

Here is my django code:

```
def contact(request):
title = 'Contact us'
form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)
confirm_message = None

if form.is_valid():
    instance = form.save()

    subject = instance.subject
    name = instance.name
    email = instance.email
    comment = instance.comment
    message = '       From : %s\n\
               Email : %s \n\
               Message: %s ' %(name, email, comment)
    emailFrom = email
    emailTo = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER

    send_mail(subject, message, emailFrom, recipient_list=[emailTo],  fail_silently=True)
    title = 'Thanks!!'
    confirm_message = "Thanks for the message we will get right back to you"
    form = None

context = {
'title':title, 
'form': form, 
'confirm_message': confirm_message,
}

return render(request, 'website/contact.html', context)
```

Comment: that's because the actual sender is yourself (your settings.py). You can't spoof the from address, gmail will display the real sender, not the one you "say you are", to try and reduce phishing.

Comment: what you can do is set the reply-to address, which will show up in gmail when you reply to the message. You can also use the following from-address format: "Bruno <me@example.com>" (with the brackets) so that even though the email address is yours, the display is changed to "Bruno".

Comment: ok. I did it like this  "%s <bruno@gmail.com>" %email,  and its now showing me the email address only when I open the  email to read it. but in the inbox its still showing 'me'.

Comment: Not sure but what if you also change the reply-to address?